# I have installed ClamAV in my linux server still I receive virus found error when attachment is added

Tags: linux

we are adding attachment in flex ui when ever we add an attachment Clamav scans files if virus is present or not.Here whatever attachment we are adding it says virus found or clamav files are not installed.Though we have clamav files installed in our linux server.

Comment: maybe the attachment has the known signatures of a virus but is really not a virus. such as if you download an application for rooting your phone it will be marked as a virus due to what the program does.

Comment: The file we are adding as attachments contain only single email address also it says virus found irrespective of what we attach.

Comment: Probably there is virus on the server. i.e. you might be sending email from `myEmail@yourdomain.com` and here in this case your domain might contain some malware.